# The correct way to generate template literals from a function

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

I have a function which takes an argument of `id` and returns a template literal:

```
const template = (id) => {
    return `<div style="box-sizing: border-box; height: 32px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ECECEC; color: #282828; padding: 8px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
 <div style="padding-right: 8px; margin-top: 8px;">
    [Image id=`${id}` align="style"] /* CMS specific code, just for clarification */
 </div>
 <div style="">
    <h2 style="font-size: 14px;">Champions League</h2>
 </div>
</div>`
  }
```

And an array which holds a bunch of IDs:

```
const cmsImgIds = [448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454]
```

I loop through `cmsImgIds` and write the template to the document:

```
  for (element in cmsImgIds) {
    console.log(element, 'element')
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = template(element)
  }
```

I expect each template to be written to the document 7 times.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
window.onload = function(){  
  
  const cmsImgIds = [448, 449, 450, 451, 452, 453, 454]  
  
  const template = (id) => {
    return `<div style="box-sizing: border-box; height: 32px; border-bottom: 1px solid #ECECEC; color: #282828; padding: 8px; display: flex; align-items: center;">
 <div style="padding-right: 8px; margin-top: 8px;">
    [Image id="${id}" align="style"]
 </div>
 <div style="">
    <h2 style="font-size: 14px;">Champions League</h2>
 </div>
</div>`
  }
  
  for (element in cmsImgIds) {
    console.log(element, 'element')
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML += template(element)
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything preventing you from using [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to include a runnable example here on Stack Overflow, saving people a trip to another site...

Comment: Thanks @HereticMonkey I didn't know I could do that

Comment: No problem. It's kind of a hidden feature. It does point out that you have a syntax error (click Run code snippet); you should be using double quotes around `${id}`, not tick marks. You could also just use `innerHTML += template(element)`.

Comment: Lol nice, that fixes it thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here it will replace the innerHTML each loop inside the for, then you will only have the last element what you should do is:

```
document.getElementById('root').appendChild(template(element))
```

Sorry, this would be if the template was an HTMLElement

you could generate a big string inside the for, then se it as innerHTML

```
let html = '';
for (element in cmsImgIds) {
  console.log(element, 'element')
  html = html + template(element)
}
document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = html
```